# gRPC Java server: is there any way to get the original message bytes that were received from a client?

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

Since Protobuf message serialization format is not deterministic across platforms and software versions, just serializing the message back using `toByteArray()` method will not necessarily produce the original bytes. Is there any other way to access them with gRPC Java server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the correct way is to use server interceptors:

```
ServerBuilder.forPort(port)
        .addService(
            ServerInterceptors.intercept(
                ServerInterceptors.useInputStreamMessages(
                    new MyMegaCoolService().bindService()
                ),
                new ServerInterceptor() {
                    @Override public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(
                        ServerCall<ReqT,RespT> call,
                        Metadata headers,
                        ServerCallHandler<ReqT,RespT> next
                    ) {
                        ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> listener = next.startCall(call, headers);
                        return new ForwardingServerCallListener
                            .SimpleForwardingServerCallListener<ReqT>(listener) {
                            @Override public void onMessage(ReqT msg) {
                                InputStream in = (InputStream)msg;

                                assert in.markSupported();
                                in.mark(MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE);

                                readMessage(in);

                                try {
                                    in.reset();
                                }
                                catch (IOException e) {
                                    throw new IllegalStateException(e);
                                }

                                super.onMessage(msg);
                            }
                        };
                    }
                }
            )
        )
        .build();
```